# Framework c# com windows Form Application

Tags: c#, framework

Estou querendo desenvolver um ERP em C# com windows Form App, gostaria de saber se existe algum framework para essa parte.

Pois pesquisei e achei o Entity, mas não encontrei se posso utilizar ele no desenvolvimento desktop.

Alguém utilização algum para agilizar o desenvolvimento?

Obrigado

Comment: pode trabalhar no desktop

Comment: Se você tá desenvolvendo com .NET, ele próprio é um framework. Entity é um ORM.

Comment: Certo Obrigado pelos comentários, mas então se uso visual studio já estou usando um framework ?

Comment: Sim amigo, se vc está usando o visual studio, você já está usando a .Net Framework. O VIsual Studio é o nosso ambiente de trabalho, aonde escrevemos nosso código e usamos os componentes e funcionalidades que ele nós oferece, a isto chamamos de IDE. A .Net framework é o "serviço" que pega o que fazemos no VS e converte em linguagem de máquina para o computador interpretar. resumindo a framework tem os recursos e o visual studio é o meio para usarmos estes recursos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o próprio .Net já é um Framework, mas dentro dele você possui várias bibliotecas e uma delas é a do [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/entity-framework), que tem o objetivo de resolver o problema de persistência de dados baseado no conceito de ORM. Você poderá utilizar o Entity em sua aplicação seja ela Desktop ou Web, mas para persistência de dados você não é obrigado a usar o Entity, poderá utilizar outro framework ORM como o [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/), ou mesmo utilizar instruções SQL para realizar os insert, update, selects, deletes dos registros das tabelas de seu sistema.
Antes de mais nada tenha em mente que essa é uma decisão muito importante para a arquitetura do seu sistema, inclusive depende do banco de dados que irá utilizar.